# Power BI Capacity

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Currently I am working on to embed Power BI content in my web application. I have implemented it with service principal and it is working as expected. But for prod environment Is it mandatory add a capacity with my report or workspace? Will it be possible to implement it without adding any capacity on prod environment ?

Comment: Microsoft Power BI capacity licensing states that for an production environment you will need a capacity. For development you can use the SP and a Power BI Pro account

Answer (score 1):

When you go in production you absolutely need a capacity but there is a new "Premium Gen2" that let you start with a low price system

more information on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-gen2-what-is

And https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/
with the strating price :

Node Type   :A1
Virtual Cores : 1
Memory  3 GB
Frontend / Backend Cores : 0.5 / 0.5
Price : $1.0081/hour

You can upgrade the pricing tier if the performance doesn't fit your needs.